# JUnit error "Unknown entity type" when using entities from a jar-file

Tags: java, git, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm struggling with an error in my Java project.

Running my code in a local project without any connection to GitHub, everything works fine. As soon as I run the Junit4 test of the same code in a project connected to GitHub, this error occurs:

> **`Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:** An exception occured while creating a query in `EntityManager`:
>
> **Exception Description:** Error compiling the query `SELECT entity FROM DoSomething entity`. Unknown entity type `DoSomething`.

I am using Eclipse, EclipseLink, PostgreSQL and JPA. The Database is on my localhost. Might there be any problems to find localhost while running the Git Project? I have a local repository for the GitProject so I can't imagine that this is really a problem.

This is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDatabase" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="secret" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
            value="database" />
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="off"/> 

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> 

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

*EDIT:
This is my entity class.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findByName", query = "SELECT r FROM DoSomething r WHERE r.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "findByPreis", query = "SELECT r FROM DoSomething r WHERE r.preis = :preis"),
})
public class DoSomething {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;
private double preis;

public DoSomething() {

}

public DoSomething(String name, double preis) {
    this.name = name;
    this.preis = preis;
}

public DoSomething(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getPreis() {
    return preis;
}

public void setPreis(double preis) {
    this.preis = preis;
}}
```

I exported the entity class into a jar-file. Then I opened a new project where the jar-file is referenced. In this project there is a class that persists the entity to the database. Due to a performance requirement I have to separate the entity and the persisting class into two projects.

This ist the persisting class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import demo.persistence.jpa.JpaUtil;


public class DoSomethingDAO {


public void save(DoSomethingDAO entity) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = JpaUtil.createEntityManager();

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(entity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        throw e;

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}


public List<DoSomethingDAO> findByName(String name) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDatabase").createEntityManager();

    List<DoSomethingDAO> bList = new ArrayList<DoSomethingDAO>();
    
    try {
        

TypedQuery<DoSomethingDAO> tQuery = em.createNamedQuery("findByName", DoSomethingDAO.class);
            tQuery.setParameter("name", name);
            
            bList = tQuery.getResultList();

            em.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bList;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `DoSomething ` entity class?

Comment: This is the "DoSomething" class that you haven't told us anything about? and haven't listed in persistence.xml? GitHub has absolutely nothing to do with anything ... the classes have to be in the CLASSPATH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your persistence.xml not on the classpath while running in tests. Tests scope has another classpath then main one. But I don't know how to set up this in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<class>packagename.DoSomehting</class>
```

for all classes to the xml-File. Works fine now.